# Count number of nodes in a modified Tree

Tags: haskell

I am practicing functional programming using Haskell.

I have been playing around with **Data.Tree**, trying to create some functions.

The normal definition for the Tree looks something like this:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

This is a Binary tree. But what I want to do now is have a tree where every Node can have any number of nodes (not just 2). So, the definition would use a list of Nodes like this:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]
```

What I want to do now is have 2 functions to: *count the number of nodes in the tree, and also find if a Node exists in the tree*, though I'm not too sure where to start. Could someone lend some advice?

Here is the function for counting nodes in a regular Binary Tree:

```
countNodes (Leaf _) = 1
countNodes (Node _ left right) = countNodes left + countNodes right + 1
```

and for finding if a node exists:

```
existsNode p (Leaf x) = p x
existsNode p (Node x left right) = p x || existsNode p left || existsNode p right
```

Comment: How did you determine the number of nodes in the binary tree?

Comment: Please see edit :)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am representing a Tree where the children are contained in a list (my second Tree definition), and I want to have those functions work for that data type, though not quite sure how.

Comment: I'll help you out with the first one: `countNodes (Node _ [cs]) = 1 + sum (map countNodes cs)` - maybe you can try to come up with something similar for the second - look at [`any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any) - this will go where `sum (map  ...) ` is ;) and you probably need `==` and `||` ...

Comment: Thanks for those tips, I think that makes a lot of sense :)

Answer (score 0):

you could do this recursively again (as your original versions for an binary tree) - by matching on the *children*-list - but I think it's nicer to use some library functions:

```hs
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]

countNodes :: Tree a -> Int
countNodes (Node _ cs) = 
    1 + sum (map countNodes cs)

existsNode :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> Bool
existsNode p (Node a cs) = 
    p a || any (existsNode p) cs
```

(note that there was an error in my comment - it's `cs` not `[cs]` sorry)

`existsNode` is using a predicate (`a -> Bool`) as it seem you original one did too.

---

in case you need it - this is a version using pattern-matching and recursion (only on the first one - I think you can do the second yourself):

```hs
countNodes' :: Tree a -> Int
countNodes' (Node _ []) = 1
countNodes' (Node a (c:cs)) = 
    countNodes' c + countNodes' (Node a cs)
```

I tried to keep this really simple/short but as you can probably see it's rather wasteful in the way I try to prevent from using something like `map` on the children list